# FF Not Picking Up CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

FF won't show the imported font or the gradient & border-radius on some of the divs, but I'm really not sure why.

[Here's the site](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html), where the fonts for headings should be Arial Rounded MT Bold, the middle h2 gradients don't show, the right & left nav divs and titles should be with a border-radius of 5px and the Twitter speech bubbles don't show correctly.

If someone could perhaps compare to Chrome it'd be great, and that's how it should look..

Here's the CSS for the fonts:

```
@font-face {font-family:'Arial Rounded MT Bold';src: url("/Fonts/ArialRoundedBold.ttf") format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family:'Arial Rounded MT Light';src: url("/Fonts/ArialRoundedLight.ttf") format('truetype');}
```

The H2 Middle gradients that aren't showing:

```
#middle h2 {margin-bottom:5px;color:#293346;font-size:22px;padding:3px 2.3%;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EBEBEC), to(lightGrey));background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEC,  #lightGrey);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EBEBEC', endColorstr='#dcdcdc');border:1px solid #d5d5d5;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;border-top-left-radius: 10px;}
```

The top-left nav heading for 'Directory' for example that should have a border-radius:

```
#left-nav .quickjump h2 {border:1px solid #4D535C;padding:2px 0;background:#676E79;color:#fff;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #5d5e80;font-size:14px;border-top-right-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:0;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;text-indent:10px;-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#808792), to(#727A86));background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #808792,  #727A86);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#808792', endColorstr='#727A86');}
```

And the right-nav speech bubbles, where the 'speech' bit isn't showing right:

```
.twtr-tweet {
    background-color: #Ffffff !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #777777;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;float: left; !important;
    width:60%;}

.twtr-tweet::before {
    background-color: #Ffffff;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}
#tweet-id-1 {float: left;margin: 5px 10%;}
#tweet-id-1::before {box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );left: -9px;}
#tweet-id-2 {float: right;margin: 5px 10%;}
#tweet-id-2::before {box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );right: -9px;}
#tweet-id-3 {float: left;margin:5px 10%;}
#tweet-id-3::before {box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );left: -9px;}
#tweet-id-4 {float: right;margin: 5px 10%;}
#tweet-id-4::before {box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );right: -9px;}
```

Any help is very much appreciated..

** I fixed the issues-  the fontface was the wrong URL & the border-radius:0; from IE cancelled out the Moz radius...

The gradient had an extra space between the characters.  Had looked at it for ages then suddenly found them.. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you should at least also include a .EOT for Internet explorer, FF does support ttf, and your font-face syntax looks right.  When I look at the site in FF the text looks fine.

As for the gradient, however, the -moz- is written wrong.

You have
`-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEC,  #lightGrey);` and you can't use `#lightGrey` because that doesn't make sense.  The `#` denotes it as a hex code.

It should be like:

`-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebec 0%, #cccccc 100%);`

And instead of that crazy syntax you're using for all the border-radii you should just use something like...

`border-radius: Apx Bpx Cpx Dpx`

...where A is the pixels you want for top left, B is top-right, C is bottom right, D is bottom left.

and then instead of declaring each of those styles over and over again for each browser...

Go get Lea Verou's prefixfree.js at http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/, link to the script at the bottom of your html, and let her JavaScript add the prefixes for you depending on the browser one is using to visit the page.

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but have you tried changing the font family name in your `@font-face` declaration to something *without* quotes?

What happens if you try `@font-face {font-family:arial-rounded-bold;src: url("/Fonts/ArialRoundedBold.ttf") format('truetype');}`

For example?

ALSO... best practices for @font-face calls for **four** font files: SVG, WOFF, EOT, and TTF. I'm not sure which one firefox uses, but for cross browser compatibility, I would seriously recommend converting your TTF to the other formats.

You can do that here:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0):

Could this mistake be part of the issue?

```
 vertical-align: top;float: left; !important;
```

Should it be:

```
vertical-align: top;
float:left !important;
```

No semicolon after 'left'